# Component is not re-rendering after changing state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a problem. Whenever I click on Activate or Deactivate Button the state (statusUpdated) gets updated but the component does not gets re-rendered. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here and help me reolve the issue.

On ComponentDidMount I am calling an api to get users list then in an array I am storing some data. I want to activate or deactivate user by clicking button. When user clicks on any button the respective function is called. In the respective function I have again called api and after that I am updating state which is getting updated but the component is not getting re-rendered.

Please help me resolve the issue.
Thank you.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            usersList       : [],       
            buttonClicked   : false,
        };

        this.DeactivateUser = this.DeactivateUser.bind (this);
        this.ActivateUser = this.ActivateUser.bind (this);
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        var usersList = [];
        apiCallHere ()
        .then ((response) => response.json ())
        .then ((findresponse) => {
            findresponse
            .sort ((x, y) => y.id - x.id)
            .map ((obj) => {
                usersList.push ({
                    Id      : obj.id,
                    Status  : obj.state === 'A' ? <button onClick={(e) => this.DeactivateUser(obj.id)}>Deactivate</button> : <button onClick={(e) => this.ActivateUser(obj.id)} >Activate</button>,
                })          
            })

            this.setState ({ usersList: usersList})
        })
    }

    ActivateUser = (id) => {
        apiCalled (id)
        .then ((response) => response.json ())
        .catch ((error) => {
            this.setState ({statusUpdated : true})
        })
    }

    DeactivateUser = (id) => {
        apiCalled (id)
        .then ((response) => response.json ())
        .catch ((error) => {
            this.setState ({statusUpdated : true})
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div> {this.state.usersList.map ((obj) => {
                      <li>obj</li>
                  })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: On activate and deactivate you're only updating state in the case of an error.

Comment: Yep, and as I stated the state is getting updated but component is not getting re-rendered.

Comment: So how it will re-render if you do nothing?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood what you meant by nothing.

Comment: Can you show your render function? Or at least the part of it that's dependant on the state? @egorchik is saying that if the API call succeeds, then you don't change the state (or do anything at all), so nothing is going to happen

Comment: I have updated the code. I am using something like this in render. I am showing list of user id and button respectively. And as for API call, it never succeeds hence state will always update.

Comment: Are you sure the `catch` block is getting executed? It looks like it is not. Can you debug and add a console statement and check if the catch block is executing?

Comment: @Ketan ok so your `render()` just renders the state user list. So when the API call fails, it changes the `statusUpdated ` value in the state, but that value doesn't affect anything that's rendered. So nothing will change. Also, you're rendering the entire object in your map: `<li>obj</li>`. Firstly, since it's a variable you'll need to wrap it in curly braces, secondly you'll want to render the object's specific properties, not just the entire object.

Comment: @Jayce but my 'obj' is an object that contains id and status and based on status I am showing button either Activate Button or Deactivate Button. On clicking button my status is getting updated which  I think should affect the render function. Am I wrong ? and Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: @Ketan yes when your state gets updated it will re-render, but the only thing you're rendering is the list. The value of `statusUpdated` doesn't affect what's being rendered, so nothing on the screen will actually change. What are you expecting to happen when `statusUpdated` is set to true? What difference to you expect to see on the screen? You said it "should affect the render function", what does that mean?

Comment: @Jayce Ok, I understood my mistake. I am not calling statusUpdated in my render and expecting for component to re-render. It's a conceptual error. I need to read more. I wanted button to switch from Activate to Deactivate and vice-versa after calling api on its click. I understood now. Sorry and thanks for you time.